# Unity: getting a maximum of 10 out of 20 questions quiz game Multiple Choice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have followed the tutorial of the Unity Quiz game and wondered that If i want the game to present only up to 10 questions but the pool of questions have 20 or so so this is the script from the tutorial that I have somewhat edited.

> I have a script called Game Controller

```
void Start()
        {
            dataController = FindObjectOfType<DataController>();                                // Store a reference to the DataController so we can request the data we need for this round

        currentRoundData = dataController.GetCurrentRoundData();                            // Ask the DataController for the data for the current round. At the moment, we only have one round - but we could extend this
        questionPool = currentRoundData.questions;                                          // Take a copy of the questions so we could shuffle the pool or drop questions from it without affecting the original RoundData object

        timeRemaining = currentRoundData.timeLimitInSeconds;                                // Set the time limit for this round based on the RoundData object
        UpdateTimeRemainingDisplay();
        playerScore = 0;
        questionIndex = 0;

        ShowQuestion();
        isRoundActive = true;
    }


void ShowQuestion()
    {
        RemoveAnswerButtons();

        QuestionData questionData = questionPool[questionIndex];                            // Get the QuestionData for the current question
        questionText.text = questionData.questionText;                                      // Update questionText with the correct text

        for (int i = 0; i < questionData.answers.Length; i ++)                              // For every AnswerData in the current QuestionData...
        {
            GameObject answerButtonGameObject = answerButtonObjectPool.GetObject();         // Spawn an AnswerButton from the object pool
            answerButtonGameObjects.Add(answerButtonGameObject);
            answerButtonGameObject.transform.SetParent(answerButtonParent);
            answerButtonGameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            AnswerButton answerButton = answerButtonGameObject.GetComponent<AnswerButton>();
            answerButton.SetUp(questionData.answers[i]);                                    // Pass the AnswerData to the AnswerButton so the AnswerButton knows what text to display and whether it is the correct answer
        }
    }
```

> The script that Hold the Questions and Answers

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DataController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public RoundData[] allRoundData;

    void Start ()  
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

        SceneManager.LoadScene ("MenuScreen");
    }

    public RoundData GetCurrentRoundData()
    {
        return allRoundData [0];
    }
}
```